# Consolidate list of file paths

Tags: python

I have a list of directory paths that I am trying to reduce to the smallest list possible.  For example:

```
bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images/hd-media
bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images/cdrom/xen
bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images/cdrom
bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images
bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543
```

I can get rid of `bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543` because it can collapse into `bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images` which I can also get rid of because it can collapse into `bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images/cdrom` which then collapses into `bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images/cdrom/xen`

I know there is a way to do this, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: How are you creating the list? You may be able to filter at that step. For example, only add to list if the dir has no sub-dirs.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You want to remove all the directories that are a "prefix" to another directory in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could put the directories into a tree structure and then get the leaf nodes from that tree, which are the directories that are not a parent to another directory in the list.

```
dirs = ["bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images/hd-media",
        "bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images/cdrom/xen",
        "bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images/cdrom",
        "bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images",
        "bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543"]

tree = {}
for d in dirs:
    t = tree
    for x in d.split("/"):
        t = t.setdefault(x, {})
# {'bionic': {'main': {'installer-amd64': {'20101020ubuntu543': {'images': {'hd-media': {}, 'cdrom': {'xen': {}}}}}}}}

def leafs(tree):
    for x in tree:
        if tree[x]:
            for l in leafs(tree[x]):
                yield x + "/" + l
        else:
            yield x

for l in leafs(tree):
    print(l)
# bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images/hd-media
# bionic/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu543/images/cdrom/xen
```

Comment: Keep getting an invalid syntax error on the line yield f"{x}/{l}"

Comment: @TroyWard That sort of format string only works in newer versions of Python. Updated with a more general way of doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler solution: If you sort the list, it is enough to compare every dir with the next one in the list:

```
dirs = sorted(dirs)

result = []
for i, d in enumerate(dirs):
    if i == len(dirs) - 1 or not dirs[i+1].startswith(d): # unique
        result.append(d)

for d in result:
    print(d)
```

or, as a list comprehension:

```
result = [
    d for i, d in enumerate(sorted(dirs))
    if i == len(dirs) - 1 or not dirs[i+1].startswith(d)
]
```

Comment: Hm, I guess that should work, too. But the condition could be improved to `if i == len(dirs) - 1 or not dirs[i+1].startswith(d):`, not needing the final `append` and fixing the case of e.g. `["a", "b/a/c"]`

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for the comment. You're right. I've edited the answer.